# find augmenting path (maximal matching)

Tags: python, graph, path, matching

I have to implement a function find_augmenting_path (n, edges, matching) in Python which return None if there is no augmenting path, or return such a path in the form of a list of vertices.

edges is a list of edge ex:[(1,2), (2,3)...]
n is the number of vertice
and matching is a valide matching (a edge list)

I've been looking for how to do it since yesterday and I can't find the solution.

I have already coded a function to find out if there is an augmenting path.
I now have to code how to find this path.

If someone have an idea please tell me.
I need your help

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `networkx` module:

```
import networkx as nx

l = [(12,9), (1,2), (2,5), (4,7), (5,3), (4,9), (9,4), (1,2), (3,9), (8,5), (5,5), (1,9), (5,12)]

G = nx.DiGraph(l)

paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, 1, 9)

for path in map(nx.utils.pairwise, paths):
    print(list(path))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 3), (3, 9)]
[(1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 12), (12, 9)]
[(1, 9)]
```

That program uses `networkx` to find all possible paths that begin at `1` and end at `9`, and these numbers are changeable.